# how to converts NSMutableArray values into NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios4

hi all how to convert `NSMutableArray` values into the `NSString`
 when i did as like

```
Webservices *details=[[Webservices alloc] init];
[details getMobileNumberDetails:phnotextfield.text];

NSLog(@"longitudes Arrays from %@",details.resultData);
```

> "-91.57696007",
>       "10.343234",
>       "74.982343",
>       "76.464844",
>       "76.464844",
>       "2.256",

but when implemented like this

```
theCoordinate2.longitude = [[details.longarray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
NSLog(@"longitudes list from %@",theCoordinate2.longitude);
```

> -91.57696007

but my intention is to assign all values to `theCoordinate2.longitude`  so help me to store into string element in iphone.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do? You want to store all those values into that one variable?

I expect your problem is at the line: `[details.longarray objectAtIndex:0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
theCoordinate2.longitude = [[details.longarray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:[details.longarray objectAtIndex:1];
//and so on for index 2,3,4   stringByAppendingString:[details.longarray objectAtIndex:2

NSLog(@"longitudes list from %f",theCoordinate2.longitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Wasif, but while he was composing his answer I was composing my own version of the code you could try:

```
NSMutableArray * longitudeArray = NULL;
NSString * detailsAsString = details.resultData;
if(detailsAsString)
{
    NSArray * longitudeStringArray = [detailsAsString componentsSeparatedByString, @","];
    if(longitudeStringArray && ([longitudeStringArray count] > 0))
    {
        longitudeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: [longitudeStringArray count]];
        if(longitudeArray)
        {
            for(NSString * longitudeString in longitudeStringArray)
            {
                [longitudeArray addObject: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: [longitudeString floatValue]]];
            }
        }

    } else {
        NSLog( @"did not extract an array out of webservice data");
    }
}
```