# how to convert NSMutableArray into NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to convert (or copy?) a NSMutableArray into a NSString. I guess my problem is that I don't really understand the structure of a NSString. In my limited knowledge, a string could look like this: in iphone

Comment: Means, you want to append the array elements to form a NSString?

Comment: Actually you are spamming SO with similar kind of questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800747/how-to-store-the-data-into-nsmutablestring, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787505/how-to-converts-nsmutablearray-values-into-nsstring and the current one. Just make sure what you want and ask clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take the `NSMutableString` and append every array string into your string

like

```
string = [string appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", [array objectAtIndex:i]]];
```

Comment: it is quite interesting that the worse answer got accepted. Dear Future Reader: Please check Leena's answer.

Comment: oh, and actually that code is wrong, `-appendString:` works in-place and there-for does not return anything, while NSStrings's `-stringByAppendingString:` returns a new string.

Comment: the signature is `- (void)appendString:(NSString *)aString`, so it is NOT returning a string.

Comment: and you changed the code in-between, but you are calling the immutable NSString's method `-stringByAppendingString:`, so your answer is still a mess, as you are referring to NSMutableString. But even if you fix that, your answer is still horribly inefficient.

Comment: Here your code is not even compiling `Semantic Issue: Assigning to 'NSMutableString *' from incompatible type 'void'`, and you included a new bug: `stringWithFormat:` needs a objective-c string: `@"%@"`

Answer (score 59):

Try this code:-

```
 NSString *string = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```