# How can I convert NSMutableArray into NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am trying to convert (or copy?) a `NSMutableArray` into a `NSString`. I guess my problem is
that I don't really understand the structure of a `NSString`. After conversion I want to
attached it in email body. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail
{
    NSLog(@"sendEmail");
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    [textView1 resignFirstResponder];
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        // set the sendTo address
        NSMutableArray *recipients = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        [recipients addObject:@"example@yahoo.com"];
        MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [controller setSubject:@"Iphone Game"];
        NSString *string = [string appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", [viewArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [controller setMessageBody:string isHTML:NO];
        [controller setToRecipients:recipients];
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller release];
    }
    else 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
 message:@"Your device is not set up for email." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your problem,can u explain clearly?

Comment: same like this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802543/how-to-convert-nsmutablearray-into-nsstring/8802630#8802630

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT:

after reading your comment, it is pretty much clear that what you are trying to do is archiving/unarchiving an array containing objects of various kinds. So, you should try using:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
```

to get an `NSData` object that you can then send as an attachment with an email message (or in whatever other persistency layer you need).

Keep in mind that this approach will work only if the objects stored in the array support the `NSCoding` protocol (you can check that in the reference for each type you are using: it clearly lists all the supported protocols). Considered that you say that your object are already stored as NSData, there should be no problem. Just archive the array, so you will be able to unarchive it later, if required.

If you have some custom type that does not support `NSCoding`, you will need to implement it as described in [Encoding and Decoding Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Tasks/codingobjects.html).

OLD ANSWER:

I am not sure I understand your problem, but what about using [`componentsJoinedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString%3a)

E.g.:

```
NSString *string = [viewArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Doing like this, the content of your array (provided it is made of strings) will be presented as a list of strings. If you use `description`, your array will be converted into a string without giving you much control on its format (it will add curly braces and other syntactic sugar).

Comment: I suspect it probably should just be `NSString *string = [viewArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];`.  Looking at the code in the original post there is no preexisting `string` to append to.

Comment: thanx for quick response ...i implemented u r code ...its reserve the bytes in the memory but not show there..here is code..
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:viewArray];
  
  
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
[controller addAttachmentData:image mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:nil]; 
get this worning....: warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct UIImage *', expected 'struct NSData *' when passing argument 1 of 'addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:' from distinct Objective-C type

Comment: you don't need to create the `UIImage` from the `NSData`. Simply pass `data` into `addAttachmentData`, with mimeType:@"application/octet-stream"; although I have to say, it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: maybe you should provide in your question an example of all those data you have and the kind of mail you would like to send...

Comment: dear a lot of thanx for helping me so for..but if u like to give me your  own Email..then i will send u code related to this issue..i am currenty working on notelist application..bcz here is not possible for me to post all that data..waiting for u r reply...

Comment: @sergio please check this link.here i think you can understand my problem well..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479036/nsmutablearray-data-attachement-with-e-mail-body

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what you wanted to do was create a loop on all the elements in `viewArray` and append them to an NSString `string`.  However, as @sergio has suggested, I think `componentsJoinedByString` would be a better option.

This is what your method would look like with that change,  I have also cleaned up some other parts of the method.  It looks like there was a memory leak, `recipients`, in your original version.

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail
{
    NSLog(@"sendEmail");

    [textView resignFirstResponder];

    [textView1 resignFirstResponder];

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        // set the sendTo address
        NSArray *recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"example@yahoo.com"];

        MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [controller setSubject:@"Iphone Game"];

        NSString *string = [viewArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];

        [controller setMessageBody:string isHTML:NO];

        [controller setToRecipients:recipients];

        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller release];

    }
    else 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                        message:@"Your device is not set up for email." 
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];

        [alert release];
    }

}
```

This will combine the elements of the `viewArray` and place a newline `\n` between each element.  You could replace the `@"\n"` with `@""` or `@" "` depending on exactly what you want to do. If the elements of the array are not `NSString`s then the elements `description` method will be called and the output of that used in the resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the format you'd like your string to have. You could always use the array's description like this:

```
NSString *myString = [myArray description];
```

Comment: Also all these custom objects are store in my nsmutablearray in Nsdata formate.